# I want to get weekdays for common time sets from the following hashmap

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have a following hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, String> days = new HashMap<String, String>(){
    days.put("MON", "9-5");
    days.put("TUE", "9-4");
    days.put("WED", "9-5");
    days.put("THU", "9-5");
    days.put("FR", "9-5");
    days.put("SAT", "Closed");
    days.put("SUN", "Closed");
};
```

I want to display following output:

`MON-WED-THU-FRI : 9-5,
 TUE: 9-4,
 SAT-SUN : Closed`

NOTE: The value of hashmap("9-5") may change depending upon the inputs from admin panel

I have done the below code but its too lengthy:

```
private void days() {

    String timing1 = null;
    String timing2 = null;
    String timing3 = null;
    String timing4 = null;
    String timing5 = null;
    String timing6 = null;
    String timing7 = null;

    ArrayList<String> time1 =new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> time2 =new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> time3 =new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> time4 =new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> time5 =new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> time6 =new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> time7 =new ArrayList<>();
```

Iterating over the hash map and taking value ie time storing in respected variable

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : days.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("key" + key + "Val" + value.toString());

    if (timing1 ==null || timing1.equals(value.toString())){
        timing1 = value.toString();
        continue;
    }

    if (timing2 ==null || timing2.equals(value.toString())){
        timing2 = value.toString();
        continue;
    }

    if (timing3 ==null || timing3.equals(value.toString())){
        timing3 = value.toString();
        continue;
    }

    if (timing4 ==null || timing4.equals(value.toString())){
        timing4 = value.toString();
        continue;
    }

    if (timing5 ==null || timing5.equals(value.toString())){
        timing5 = value.toString();
        continue;
    }

    if (timing6 ==null || timing6.equals(value.toString())){
        timing6 = value.toString();
        continue;
    }

    if (timing7 ==null || timing7.equals(value.toString())){
        timing7 = value.toString();
    }
}
```

Based on value from hash-map appending the key ie. days name(eg. MON) to the respected array-list

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : days.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();

    if (timing1!=null && timing1.equals(value.toString())){
        time1.add(key);
        continue;
    }

    if (timing2!=null && timing2.equals(value.toString())){
        time2.add(key);
        continue;
    }

    if (timing3!=null && timing3.equals(value.toString())){
        time3.add(key);
        continue;
    }

    if (timing4!=null && timing4.equals(value.toString())){
        time4.add(key);
        continue;
    }

    if (timing5!=null && timing5.equals(value.toString())){
        time5.add(key);
        continue;
    }

    if (timing6!=null && timing6.equals(value.toString())){
        time6.add(key);
        continue;
    }

    if (timing7!=null && timing7.equals(value.toString())){
        time7.add(key);
        // continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask this Kind of question at [codereview.SE]. Because it is about running code and how you can make it better

Comment: Do not use toString on the object, cast it to a string here;  `String value = (String)entry.getValue();`, so .toString is not longer needed

Answer (score 1):

Please see if below helps. The values are not ordered as per this output though.

This prints: 9-4 TUE

9-5 THU WED FR MON

Closed SAT SUN

```
public void formatMap(HashMap<String,String> hMap){
    HashMap<String, String> formattedMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Set<String> lKeys = (Set)hMap.keySet();

    for(String sKey : lKeys){

        String sValue = hMap.get(sKey);
        if(formattedMap.get(sValue) == null){
            formattedMap.put(sValue, sKey);
        }else{
            String temp = formattedMap.get(sValue);
            temp += " "+sKey;
            formattedMap.put(sValue, temp);
        }

    }

    lKeys = (Set)formattedMap.keySet();
    for(String s : lKeys){
        System.out.println(s +" "+formattedMap.get(s));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it would be easier to use some objects :

First a class to store schedules

```
package schedule;

public class DaySchedule {

    String weekDay;
    int minHour, maxHour;
    boolean open;

    public DaySchedule(String weekDay, int minHour, int maxHour, boolean open) {
        this.weekDay = weekDay;
        this.minHour = minHour;
        this.maxHour = maxHour;
        this.open = open;
    }

    public String getWeekDay() {
        return weekDay;
    }


    /**
     * Returns a unique key based on min and max hour
     * -1 is the key for closed status
     * @return int value
     */
    public String getKey() {
        if (open)
            return String.valueOf(minHour)+"-"+String.valueOf(maxHour);
        else
            return "Closed";
    }



}
```

Then a utility class to build the final result.

```
package schedule;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class ScheduleBuilder {

    HashMap<String, StringBuilder> builderHashMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void addSchedule(DaySchedule daySchedule) {
        String key = daySchedule.getKey();

        if (builderHashMap.containsKey(daySchedule.getKey())) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = builderHashMap.get(key);
            // If there is a string builder, there is already something in it, so add a -
            stringBuilder.append('-');
            stringBuilder.append(daySchedule.getWeekDay());
        } else {
            builderHashMap.put(key, new StringBuilder(daySchedule.getWeekDay()));
        }

    }


    public String toString(){

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        Iterator iterator = builderHashMap.entrySet().iterator();
           while (iterator.hasNext()) {

               if(result.length()>0){
                   result.append(',');
               }

               Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
               result.append(pair.getValue());
               result.append(":");
               result.append(pair.getKey());
               iterator.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
           }
      return result.toString();
    }
}
```

And to test...

```
package schedule;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ArrayList<DaySchedule> dayScheduleArrayList = new ArrayList<DaySchedule>(7);

        dayScheduleArrayList.add(new DaySchedule("MON", 9, 5, true));
        dayScheduleArrayList.add(new DaySchedule("TUE", 9, 4, true));
        dayScheduleArrayList.add(new DaySchedule("WED", 9, 5, true));
        dayScheduleArrayList.add(new DaySchedule("THU", 9, 5, true));
        dayScheduleArrayList.add(new DaySchedule("FR", 9, 5, true));
        dayScheduleArrayList.add(new DaySchedule("SAT", 0, 0, false));
        dayScheduleArrayList.add(new DaySchedule("SUN", 0, 0, false));

        ScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder = new ScheduleBuilder();
        for (Iterator<DaySchedule> iterator = dayScheduleArrayList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            DaySchedule daySchedule = iterator.next();
            scheduleBuilder.addSchedule(daySchedule);
        }

        System.out.println("scheduleBuilder = " + scheduleBuilder);

    }
}
```